# My coworker accidentally deleted a production google cloud datastore , is there a way to recover it

Tags: google-cloud-platform, datastore

My coworker accidentally deleted a whole google cloud datastore database,
is there any way to recover it?

Comment: Not likely, but ask Google support as soon as you can, maybe they have ways.

Comment: fyi this is a question for Customer Support, not Stack Overflow (plus this isn't a programming question). Helpful reading: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 1):

Did you have backups enabled? If so you can restore a backup using the following
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/backups#restore_data_from_a_database_backup

> **Restore data from a database backup**
> A restore operation writes the data from a backup to a new Datastore mode database. To begin a restore operation, use the `gcloud alpha firestore databases restore` command:
>
> ```
> gcloud alpha firestore databases restore \
> --source-backup=projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/backups/BACKUP_ID \
> --destination-database='DATABASE_ID'
> ```
>
> - PROJECT_ID: Your project ID.
> - LOCATION: The location of the database backup and the location of the new database created for the restored data.
> - BACKUP_ID: The ID of a backup. You can view the ID each backup when you list all backups.
> - DATABASE_ID: A database ID for the new database. You cannot use a database ID that is already in use. The database mode will match that of the backup.
>
> The output will include metadata, name, and response components:

Comment: sadly we dont have backup enabled